# How to match distribution types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I bunch of Shape union types (Rectangle and Circle), and each kind of Shape has different props, like Rectangle has width and height, while Circle has radius.

I have an application, which take the input and randomly draw shapes. so:

- input: an object, the key is the name of the shape, and the value is the type of the shape
- output: an object as well, the key is the name of the shape, and the value is the props of the shape

I want to have a store which save multiple shapes inputs and outputs like below:

```js
// Valid one:
{
  inputs: { house: 'Rectangle', football: 'Circle' },
  outputs: { house: { width: 30, height: 10 }, football: {radius: 0.2 } },
};

// Invalid one:
{
  inputs: { house: 'Rectangle', football: 'Circle' },
  outputs: { house: { radius: 10 }, football: {radius: 0.2 } },
};
```

To implement the above feature, I tried several ways, but so far I didn't find the right solution, all didn't fail properly.

### Shape types

```js
type Rectangle = {
  type: 'Rectangle';
  props: {
    width: number;
    height: number;
  };
};

type Circle = {
  type: 'Square';
  props: {
    radius: number;
  };
};

type Shape = Rectangle | Circle;
```

### 1st try

```js
type Draw1 = {
  inputs: { [key: string]: Shape['type'] };
  outputs: { [key: string]: Shape['props'] };
};

const drawHouse1_1: Draw1 = {
  inputs: { house: 'Rectangle' },
  outputs: { house: { width: 3, height: 4 } },
};

const drawHouse1_2: Draw1 = {
  inputs: { house: 'Rectangle' },
  outputs: { house: { radius: 10 } }, // <-- obviously it is wrong cos a Rectangle should not have radius prop
};
```

### 2nd try

```js
type FilterShape<Shape, Type> = Shape extends { type: Type } ? Shape : never;
type Draw2<T extends { [key: string]: Shape['type'] }> = {
  inputs: T;
  outputs: { [key in keyof T]: FilterShape<Shape, T[key]>['props'] };
};

const drawHouse2_1: Draw2<{ [key: string]: Shape['type'] }> = {
  inputs: { house: 'Rectangle' },
  outputs: { house: { width: 3, height: 4 } },
};

const drawHouse2_2: Draw2<{ [key: string]: Shape['type'] }> = {
  inputs: { house: 'Rectangle' },
  outputs: { house: { radius: 10 } }, // <-- obviously it is wrong cos a Rectangle should not have radius prop
};
```

Please check [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-cdn-40zsk?file=/src/index.ts) for the above code.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving it would be to use a genetic so the language knowns which type you are talking about:

```
type Draw<T extends Shape> = {
  inputs: { [key: string]: T["type"] };
  outputs: { [key: string]: T["props"] };
};

const drawHouse1_1: Draw<Rectangle> = {
  inputs: { house: "Rectangle" },
  outputs: { house: { width: 3, height: 4 } }
};

const drawHouse1_2: Draw<Rectangle> = {
  inputs: { house: "Rectangle" },
  outputs: { house: { radius: 10 } }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, it works perfect. I might over complicated the issue at beginning.